# /execute @p [tag=Visitor] ~1 ~ ~ /say Test doesn't work in Command Blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I run this command normally it works:
**/execute @p [tag=Visitor] ~1 ~ ~ /say Test**
...
But if I try to run it in a command block it says:
**Syntax Error: Unexpected "]": at "xecute @s[>>]<<"**

Answer (score 1):

The format that you used is the pre-1.13 command format. Instead of what you did, try this command:

```
/execute as @p[tag=Visitor] run /say Test
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest removing the / at the beginning if it is to be place into a command block, as I have run into errors where it doesn't like the /, and disregards the rest of the command.